# android update custom view in asynctask

Tags: java, android, view, android-asynctask

Ok, I have a custom view which plays gifs from the internet. Therefor I need to add an url to my view to download the gif. But I can't seem to update my custom view inside my `asynctask`. I need to add an url string to my custom view `gifView.setUrl()`. It works in the onCreate Class but it gives me null in asynctask.

Oncreate class

```
    GifView gifView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        id = extras.getInt("id");
        String idStr = String.valueOf(id);

        String extension = extras.getString("extension");
        if(extension.equals(".gif")){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_gif);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            gifView = (GifView)findViewById(R.id.gifview);
            titleStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleTXT);
            postInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.infoTXT);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

//the url
            new getJsonInfoGif().execute("http://www.website.com/jsonApi");
        }else{
```

Asynctask

```
public class getJsonInfoGif extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading post...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return GET(strings[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{'postinfo':[" + res + "]}");
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("postinfo");
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            //post title
            titleStr.setText(obj.getString("name"));
            //category and maker full name
            //large image
            JSONObject imgObj = obj.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
            gifView.setUrl("http://www.website.com/my.gif");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

GifView.java

```
public void setUrl(String urlStr){
    this.urlStr = urlStr;
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}

public String getUrl(){
    return this.urlStr;
}

public void init(final Context context)throws IOException{
    setFocusable(true);
    movie = null;
    movieWidth = 0;
    movieHeight = 0;
    movieDuration = 0;
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                Log.d("DEBUG", "URL" + urlStr);
                URL url = new URL(urlStr);

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    inputStream = http.getInputStream();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    movie = Movie.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    movieWidth = movie.width();
                    movieHeight = movie.height();
                    movieDuration = movie.duration();

                    ((PostActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            invalidate();
                            requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Here is the Log from the url, it gives me null if I add the url inside my asynctask in Activity.

```
11-07 14:41:58.821    5674-6076/svenmobile.tools.showcase D/DEBUG﹕ URLnull
```

What I want to know is what the problem is and how to solve it if possible. 
Thanks in advance, Sven

Comment: In your doInBackground  method of your AsyncTask, what return the GET(String) method ? Why not simply do "return strings[0]" ?

Comment: because I need to parse json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you called `init()` before `setUrl()`.

You can pass it the url in the contructor, or `public void init(final Context context, String urlStr)throws IOException{`

I also suggest you to move all that network code to `doInBackground`